SRAM PC-1 quick link?
What quick link would work on this chain for my fixie?  Are the SRAM 10 or 11 speed links compatible?

If this is your chain   https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/cn-1-a1   then it specifically says 1/8" chain
You will need a quick link for 1/8" chain, which might also be called "single speed chain"
By comparison, chains for derailleur bikes will be 3/32" (whereas yours is 4/32" inch wide)  That difference means none of the multi-speed chain parts will fit your chain.
Any chain master link you need will be specified as 1/8" or single speed.   I can't find a SRAM part; they should have one in their lineup.   BBB and KMC definitely have one.
